# Delete all directories except the most recent

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'd like to write a script that delete all the directories (that are not empty) from a directory, but keep the most recent one. Is that possible, and how?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do this using `find`.

```
find -type d ! -wholename $(find -type d -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -1 | cut -d" " -f2) ! -wholename "." -exec rm -r {} +
```

Command breakdown:

- `find -type d` the first part tells find to search for directories only
- `! -wholename` exclude hits with the following complete name. The following part (between `$()`) is evaluated and used as file name here

  - `$(find -type d -printf '%T+ %p\n' |` print timestamps for directories
  - `sort -r |` sort them newest to oldest
  - `head -1 |` take only the first line (newest directory)
  - `cut -d" " -f2)` remove the timestamp from the output
- `! -wholename "."` exclude hits with the complete name `.`. You cannot remove the directory, your currently working in.
- `-exec rm -r {} +` remove the matching files.

**You should run the command without the last part (`-exec rm -r {} +`) first, to see which directories will be removed.**

---

Example:

directory content:

```
Aug  4 14:38 bar/
Aug  4 14:38 bla
Aug  4 14:38 foo/
Aug  4 14:41 foobar/
```

running command:

```
find -type d ! -wholename $(find -type d -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -1 | cut -d" " -f2) ! -wholename "." -exec rm -r {} +
```

resulting directory content:

```
Aug  4 14:38 bla
Aug  4 14:41 foobar/
```

note that `bla` is a file and not a directory. So it will not be removed.

Comment: This excellent command does not care how deep the folder structure is. So if you want to explicitly remove (or keep) only the directories which are immediate children of the current folder, you can add the `maxdepth` switch, for example: `find -type d -maxdepth 1 ! -wholename $(find -type d -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -3 | cut -d" " -f2) ! -wholename "." -exec rm -r {} +`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, and leave it here, it might be useful for other users :

```
cd /path/to
rm -r `ls -t | awk 'NR>1'`
```

Comment: [It is not a good idea to parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), because you may get problems when you have filenames that contain whitespace. It is generally better to use `find` for this kind of things.